# Performance profiling during debug in Rider

Tags: profiling, rider

Im starting to use Jetbrains IDE Rider and I want to use the performance profiling during debugging.

Basically I want to run in debug mode, set a breakpoint, start profiling, continue execution until next breakpoint and create a snapshot from that.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manually controll when the profiling starts and ends you can disable checkbox `Collect profiling data from start` in `Run/Switch Profiling Configurations/Edit Configurations/ Profiling Configurations`.
[image]

Once you have reached your breakpoint, click `Start Recording`. After you are done click `Get Snapshot`

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Profiling_Any_.NET_Processes.html#running-the-session-and-getting-snapshots) is a detailed guide from JetBrains